# Swift-Create custom preference page

Tags: ios, swift, settings, preference

I'm really new to iOS and Swift and I wants to make a custom Settings view like the one in Yahoo Messenger app:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxsHyNkX0zXBU0tiZEFKN0dYczg/view?usp=sharing

I couldn't find a tutorial or sample as to what controls and views needed to have the look and feel. Settings Bundle doesn't seem like it because Yahoo Messenger app settings in Settings app is different from this one.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I thought that too, but when I drag-and-drop many Table View Cells into it and then drop different controls into each cell, running only shows table with many empty rows

Comment: If you selected dynamic prototype cells you need to implement the datasource and delegate methods. Else choose static prototype cells

Comment: Thanks it works, but now I hit the problem with AutoLayout

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked for you. What's the error ?

Comment: No error but I want to make the Seperate Inset = 0 so the line cover all the way from left to right. I did that but it doesn't help, I also set 
        self.tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
but it doesn't work https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxsHyNkX0zXBTUFEZGdFQlBZekU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499366/white-space-before-separator-line-into-my-tableview

Comment: Yeah it's default like that and I think it's no big deal so I don't mind. Thanks Midhun