# UITableView - a line that appears between cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that stores photos taken - one photo per cell. Following an Xcode update some time ago the table now appears with a fine white line between the cells on the left as in pic 1. The image has always been indented from the left side of the table for some reason and it is only under this part that the white line now appears.

So I have two questions really - how can I get rid of the white line and/or the indent? The separator colour is usually the same as the background but I tried changing the separator colour in the TableView to red see what happens and I get what you see in pic 2. (The image thumbnails are irrelevant).

What I am hoping for is to keep the seperator (so there is a line between the photos) but to be abel to the colour of it so match the background colour.

[image]

Comment: Check the edit, i think i've answered your query

Comment: you can check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499366/white-space-before-separator-line-into-my-tableview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By setting `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;` That remove respirator from your `tableview`. but as per your existing code you used separator with same color. I suggest to use following code:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a separator ... just of the correct colour.

Comment: have you atlist put this code this is just make your seperate full width with correct color. atlist check the code impliemtn then comment sir

Comment: I understand now - and it works. Thanks a million. You might want to edit 'respirator' :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that is the separator of the tableview. You need to turn separators off. Heres a pic how to do so

[image]

Plz check and confirm.

## EDIT

I changed my demo file-
Colourd the cell background to green and turned separator off. As you can see here
[image]

And this is what i get after running the simulator [NOTE - I implemented the delegate and datasource methods, my `numberOfRows` has a return value of 5]

[image]

Seems like there is no space as you wanted.

Comment: That will remove the line, but leave a blank space. The spacing stays the same...

Answer (score 1):

Remove any separator from your tableView:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Then, from your `UITableViewCells` remove any space between the `UIImageView` and the view margins (setting constraints from example).

**EDIT**

You can set the separator color using the tableView property:

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a separator ... just of the correct colour.

Comment: You should make it more clear in your question. Now I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First you need set separators none

add custom separator like addSubview 
first get cell Height...

```
 UILabel *line=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cellHeight-1, cell.frame.size.width, 1)];
            line.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

 [cell addSubview:line];
```

Answer (score 0):

in the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` function, add cell.backgroundColor = {color that you want}. This will make the white space the same as your background color.